# Dynamically binding panel in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically adding data to the panel in jquery mobile however on loading the page the first time the panel doesn't work however if i refresh it it starts working properly.

```
var prof = '';
var panel = '';

$(document).one('pagecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function () {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid') !== '' || sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid') !== null && sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') !== '' || sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') !== null) {

        var jxhr = $.post(getdetails + '' + 'Users', {
            session_id: sessionStorage.sessionid,
            id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')
        }, function (data) {

            var ourhtml = getRecordDetailProfileCheck(data);
            prof = "<div style='text-align:center;'>" + ourhtml + "</div><div></div>";

            sessionStorage.setItem('prof', prof);

            panel = '<div data-role="panel" data-theme="b" data-display="push" id="mypanel"><ul data-role="listview" data-role="none" class="ulpanel"><br/><a href="#profile"><div id="panelimage"></div></a>' + prof + '<div><br/></div><li><a href="#viewquestions"><i class="lIcon main"></i>MAIN SERVICE</a></li><li><a href="#specialevents"><i class="lIcon main"></i>SPECIAL EVENTS</a></li><li><a href="#lifegroup"><i class="lIcon main"></i>LIFE GROUPS</a></li><li><a href="#sundaygroup"><i class="lIcon main"></i>SUNDAY SCHOOL</a></li><li><a href="#mainservice"><i class="lIcon main"></i>PRAYER & PRAISE</a></li><li><a href="#factory"><i class="lIcon main"></i>FACTORY & YOUTH MIX</a></li><li><a href="#volunteer"><i class="lIcon main"></i>VOLUNTEER</a></li></ul></div>';


            $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
            $("#mypanel").panel().enhanceWithin();

            var img = '';
            var va = getRecordIdPicture(data);
            if (va !== '') {

                img = file + "?session_id=" + sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid') + "&id=" + va;
            } else {
                img = 'images/man.png';
            }
            $("#mypanel #panelimage").attr('style', 'margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;width: 128px;height: 128px;border-style: solid;-webkit-border-radius: 100px;-moz-border-radius: 100px;background: url(' + img + ') no-repeat 100% 100%');

            // console.log(data);
        });
    } else {

        for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
            var key = sessionStorage.key(i);
            if (/foo/.test(key)) {
                sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        }
        $.mobile.changePage("#one", {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: true
        });
    }
});
```

Calling the panel:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
            <a href='#mypanel' data-role='button' data-iconpos='left' data-inline='true'><i class='fa fa-bars'></i></a>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/pcc.png" height="26"/></h1>
            <a href="#" class="lnklogout" data-ajax="false"><i class='fa fa-power-off'></i></a>
        </div>
```

I have tried everything i somehow feel the session is not being set? Please could someone help

Thanks

Comment: This is an external panel, are you using jQM 1.4?

Comment: Looks like a session issue http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s62pLh9j/